# What is a "penalty for a driving offence?"

Tags: visas, uk

The new UK visa application form asks if the applicant has a penalty for a driving offence. Do you have to include parking fines and 'fixed penalty notices?' How is one expected to remember thess?

There seems to be a difference between Fixed Penalty Notices and Penalty Charge Notices. Do both have to be declared? They require you declare driving offences. Is a parking ticket a driving offense?

https://www.gov.uk/parking-tickets/paying-a-ticket

There are three options on the application form: 
What was your driving offence? (Required)

Disqualification for speeding

No insurance

Something else

Comment: I know I wouldn't divulge those. I won't divulge anything that is not a felony.

Comment: Would love to hear @Gayot Fow opinion.

Comment: Note that in the UK, parking fines are not criminal, and don't appear to be included. However, driving offenses (like speeding) are criminal offenses, and paying the fixed penalty is (roughly) equivalent to a guilty plea for the criminal charge.

Comment: See https://www.gov.uk/speeding-penalties for speeding etc

Comment: Note that parking tickets are issued for a *car owner*, not a specific driver. If your car is parked incorrectly by your wife you will still get a parking ticket in your name, even though you're not at fault. Same logic applies to automatic speeding tickets in many countries - if the driver is unidentified, the car owner pays the fine and admits no fault.

Comment: @JonathanReez What about car rentals?

Comment: Same logic - fine is issued to a rental agency, not a specific person. You pay the fine, but don't admit any guilt.

Comment: The relevant UK law relating to speeding is the Road Traffic Act section 172. As the registered owner/keeper of the car you are required by law to provide the full name, address and date of birth of the driver at the time of the alleged offence. Failure to do so could result in proceedings against you for failing to supply the information as required under section 172 of the Road Traffic Act 1988. So, no the owner is not liable for the fine, the driver is, and the owner is required to tell the police who the driver was.

Comment: There was a high profile case of an MP whose wife confessed to lying that she was the  driver, both were jailed for 8 months.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie You wouldn't divulge those, but then they can either reject your application (if you write down "I'm not telling you), or correctly claim that you have been lying on your application, with worse consequences.

Comment: @djna not talking about speeding here. Only parking tickets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are similar terms with significant technical differences. Each of these can be issued relating to parking.

(Caveat: I am not a lawyer, some of this stuff is tricky)

- Parking Charge Notices are issued by private owners of land if you contravene their parking conditions. These are a civil matter, you have not committed a driving offence if you receive one of these. I would not declare these on a Visa application.
- Penalty Charge Notices (PCN) are issued by Local Government bodies when you contravene the parking regulations. Note the term "contravention of regulation" rather than "offence" - these are not treated as criminal offence, they are effectively a matter for Civil Law rather than Criminal Law. I would not declare these on a Visa application.
- Excess Charge Notice. Some councils issue these notices instead of PCNs. These are charges that are enforced by Criminal Law. It is not clear to me whether the charge itself is a criminal matter or just the **failure to pay** would be a criminal matter. I'm not sure what to declare on a Visa Application
- Fixed Penalty Notice (FPN). These can be issued by the Police if they stop you when you commit an offence. There are different categories of FPN, endorsable ones result in points on the driver's licence. FPNs can be issued for some parking offences, for example parking in particularly obstructive places. FPNs of any type are treated as driving offences and I would declare them on a Visa Application.

As to the question of how to remember what/whether offences you have committed: I can offer no great comfort, the expectation is that you should know, but I'm sure I would not know whether a parking fine from 5 years ago was a PCN or a FPN. Some folks would keep documents relating to these matters, but personally I would not have considered a paid parking fine worth keeping for long.

Answer (score 5):

From living in the UK I would say no. Driving offences in the UK are for circumstances like speeding, dangerous driving, drink driving etc that gives you penalty points on your licence. Parking tickets do not give you penalty points just a fine issued by the local authority. When we fill out forms for our car insurance we do not state if we have parking fines just driving offences like the ones i stated above and how many penalty points we have on our licence. I would not list your parking offences down as this isn't a personal offence. Your mother could be driving your car and get the parking ticket, but when issuing the ticket the parking officer doesn't know who parked the car so the ticket is for the car owner not necessarily the one who caused the offence.

here is a list of driving offences that get you points in the UK, note parking offences aren't on here

[Penalty points in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/penalty-points-endorsements/endorsement-codes-and-penalty-points)

Comment: Fixed Penalty Notices (FPNs) can be issued by the police for some parking violations. Those would typically be cases where the vehicle is causing serious obstruction. Unlike the penalty notices issued by local authorities for most parking rule contraventions these FPNs **are** a criminal offence, albeit a minor offence that does not put points on your licence.